# IntelliJ (Android Studio) Pop Up Window Background Color

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, color-scheme

I'm using Android Studio which is basically an IntelliJ IDE. For a while now my pop up windows have a white background no matter if I hover over code or use code completion. I think I checked all white(ish) color settings in Android Studio and set them to dark grey but those pop ups are still white. Please help me this drives me nuts.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no solution to this problem. As a workaround I duplicated the Darcular color scheme (named it Darcular_Custom_2022) as this has black window backgrounds. I then set all color settings as they are in my current color scheme (Darcular_edited_2018).

Now everything looks the same in the editor but the pop up windows have a black background.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change PopUp colour in
Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Popups and Hints

using Android Audio Hedgehog version 2023.1.1